# Difference between a named IIFE and calling a name function immediately?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between and IIFE

```
(function foo () {
    var var_of_concern;
}());
```

and a plain function

```
function foo () {
   var var_of_concern;
}
foo();
```

The caveat that concerned me, was if I pass nothing out of either the IIFE or the function, will the IIFE keep the memory alive longer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The opposite, though it's probably not a serious concern.

The two are syntactically not the same. The second declares a function and binds it to the local symbol "foo".  That function will remain after the function call.

The IIFE form is syntactically a single expression satement. The second form involves *two* statements, a function declaration statement and an expression statement (the function call).

The way that a function call handles local variable declarations has *nothing* to do with how the function object came into being.  If both functions in your example are the same, then there's no difference to how that space is allocated for the local variables in a function call.

*edit* — the key **syntactic** difference is this: the keyword `function` at the **start** of a new statement introduces a function declaration statement.  That syntactic form does not provide for immediate invocation.  That is, this:

```
function hello() {
  // some code
}();  // <---- ERROR
```

is a syntax error.

When the `function` keyword appears in any other context (well, any valid context), then it's **not** a function declaration — it's a function instantiation (or function definition; I'd have to check the spec) expression. These are all things that can be part of an expression in JavaScript:

```
 5
 "hello"
 false
 (2 + 5)
 (function() { alert("Hi!"); })
```

Note that the last example involves parentheses - that's commonly done to "defuse" the "Oh look a function declaration!" behavior of the parser.  That opening parenthesis means that the `function` keyword does not appear at the absolute beginning of the statement, so it's therefore just a function instantiation expression.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical I'd say so. It's still only accessible from within the function (because it's declared with `var` in both cases)

Comment: The internal variable in both cases is handled in exactly the same way. If the function does not return (or otherwise allow to "escape") a function, then the activation record will be unreferenced and garbage collected after the function exits.

Comment: ...what if the IIFE is named foo, then are they syntactically, the same?  Sorry I could not ask a more precise question 'till I got this info....that is the last clarification/edit....sorry.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical No, they're still not the same. Using a name for a function in a function instantiation expression is OK, but it's still an expression and not a function declaration statement. I'll add a bit to clarify.

Comment: @Pointy I'd say this is similar: `var a = function foo() {};` - `foo` is not a function that can be referenced from then on...you reference it by `a`.

Comment: ...I don't understand why the IIFE is not the de facto way to write modular code then...if it seemingly does not necessitate more resources...

Comment: @Ian it's similar, but it's yet another kind of statement :-)  Also giving function expressions names like that [can be a problem](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).

Comment: @livingston_mechanical well "de facto" in the JavaScript world can change hourly :-)  It is indeed a very common construction and an extremely useful one.

Comment: @Pointy Oh I know, I just wanted to point it out. This discussion just reminded me of it :) And I would never do that or suggest it, just thought of it!