# Style - Replacing named function with named IIFE

Tags: javascript

I'm refactoring some code.  Can I replace

```
function next () {
    // call next using setTimeout
}
next();
```

with

```
(function next () {
    // call next using setTimeout
}());
```

next has to be initiated and from there it will call itself a certain amount of times.

Comment: I don't get your question : did you have a problem when testing the second form ?

Comment: The second block doesn't seem to call your function -- It only defines it in a self calling closure

Comment: @dystroy I think he want to know whether two codes are equivalents ot not ?

Comment: [Why don't you just try it?](http://jsfiddle.net/jGxyN/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between a named IIFE and calling a name function immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688420/difference-between-a-named-iife-and-calling-a-name-function-immediately)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are possible, both enable recursive call (that's the point in naming the IIFE).

The only difference between them is that the second one doesn't pollute the external namespace with the function's name, which is only visible from the function. Of course a consequence is that you won't be able to call the function from elsewhere.

Comment: And you could get rid of the difference gap by placing the whole first solution in its own IIF, I suppose.

Comment: @Nile yes, but then the second form is simpler.